# Prove that $\exists a \in X$ s.t. $\bigcap ^{\infty} _{n=1} F_n = \{a\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $F_1, F_2,...$ be nonempty closed subsets of a *complete* metric space $X$ and suppose $F_1 \supseteq F_2 \supseteq ...$ and $\def\diam{\operatorname{diam}}\lim_{n\to \infty} \diam(F_n) = 0.$ Prove that $\exists a \in X$ s.t. $\bigcap ^{\infty} _{n=1} F_n = \{a\}$

Note:

$\diam(E) = \sup\{d(x,y): x,y\in E \}$ if E is bounded

and equals $\infty$ if E is unbounded

Attempt at proof:

Let $F_1, F_2,...$ be nonempty closed subsets of a metric space $X$ and suppose $F_1 \supseteq F_2 \supseteq ...$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}  \diam(F_n) = 0.$ Since $\lim_{n\to \infty}  \diam(F_n) = 0$, we know $(\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N})(\forall n \ge n_0)(F_n \text{is bounded})$. For $n\ge n_0$ we have $0 = \lim_{n\to \infty} \diam(F_n) = \limsup\{d(x,y):x,y\in F_n\}$ which implies $d(x,y) = 0$, for all $x,y \in F_n$. Then by the metric space properties, $x=y$.

Comment: The space has to be complete. Did you forget to mention that?

Comment: Now that you have "complete" added, try to prove it yourself.  Of course the completeness is essential.  See if you can come up with a sequence $a_n$, such that $a_n$ is Cauchy, and its limit $a$ has the property required.

Comment: The really terrifying thing is that this is false when $\rm{diam}(F_n)$ doesn't approach $0$.

Comment: Your attempted proof only handles uniqueness of $a$, not existence. The uniqueness part can be done much more easily, noting that $\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty F_k\subseteq F_n$ for any $n$, therefore $\diam\Bigl(\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty F_k\Bigr)\le\diam(F_n)$. Since $\diam(F_n)\to0$, this implies $\diam\Bigl(\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty F_k\Bigr)=0$ (provided the intersection is nonempty), so there is only one point in the set.

Answer (score 3):

This is false. For an example, let $X=(0,1)$ with the standard metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$, and put $F_n=(0,1/n]$.

It is true if $X$ is complete, however.

**Edit:** Assuming $X$ is complete, pick one $x_n\in F_n$ for each $n$, then show that $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence. Let $a$ be the limit of this sequence. Now you need to prove two things: $a\in F_n$ for each $n$, and no other element of $X$ has this property. I'll leave you to ponder the question how.

Comment: Hi, the metric space is complete. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: So how do I prove it for a complete metric space?

Comment: I added a hint to the answer.

Comment: Please review my edited question with an attempt at proof.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is not true.
Let $X=\mathbb Q$ with standard metric and let the $F_n=[a_n,b_n]\cap \mathbb Q$ where $\mathbb Q\ni a_n<\sqrt 2<b_n\in \mathbb Q$ and $a_n,b_n\to\sqrt 2$.

Comment: I meant to say the metric space was complete. Please help prove it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Choose arbitrary points $x_n\in F_n$ (why is that possible?) and use $\text{diam}\  F_n\to0$ to show that the sequence $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X$. Use the completeness to deduce that $(x_n)$ converges to some $a\in X$. Conclude that this is your desired $a$.